# The JFileChooser will not print of my file line by line as I wish. How can I?

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner, jfilechooser

> My code will bring up the JFileChooser GUI, but when I select a file from my desktop, it will not print the contents of the file line by line as I wish. Your help would be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file;
        Scanner in;
        int click;
        
        
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
        
        jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        click = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);
        if(jfc.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION))
        {
            file = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            try
            {
                in = new Scanner(file);
                if(file.isFile())
                {
                    while(in.hasNextLine())
                    {
                        String fileline = in.nextLine();
                        System.out.println(fileline);
                    }
                }
                in.close();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e )
            {
                System.out.println("Cannot locate file.");
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Well you're showing the save dialog.  How about try `showOpenDialog()`?

Comment: nope same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(jfc.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION))
```

Why are you comparing a `JFileChooser` with the `APPROVE_OPTION`?

You want to compare the value returned from the `showOpenDialog()` method:

```
if (click == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
```

Comment: Yep. Got it. Moving too fast focusing on the compiler. Thanks. Scary to think that one line of code and cause so much damage.

Comment: Just did it. Sorry, still new at this. lol.